# Is there a way to do asynchronous functions in the vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to get my products from my database and put that directly in my state (store vuex)
I get my products from an asynchronous function

```
    async list(options = ''){
        const res = await fetch(this.url+options, {
            method: 'GET'
            // headers: this.headers,
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        return data
    }
```

my issue is that in my store I can't use the asynchronous function

```
const state = {
    products: getProduct().then((res)=>{return res}),
    consumption: []
}
```

I get a Promesse and I would like get my array of objects

Comment: You could just setup an action (called at init) that initializes your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify you vuex store and add an action which will fetch the data afor you then call the mutaion to update your state:

```
export default {
  state: {
    products: [],
    consumption: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
      state.products = products;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchProducts({ commit }, { url, options, headers }) {
      const res = await fetch(url + options, {
            method: 'GET'
            headers,
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      commit('SET_PRODUCTS', data);
    },
  }
}
```

Then when needed (at the init of your component ?) you just need to launch the action:

```
this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts');
```